# js and css working only in index.php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Try to simplify my problem.

For example i got files `index.php` and `about.php`

`about.php` - is **full copy** of `index.php`

content of index.php and about.php:

```
<? include 'head.php'; ?>
//some content (problem not here, because for debugging I am copy index to about by ctrl+a ctrl+c)
<? include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

content of head.php

```
<!-- Theme CSS -->
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

<!-- Skins Theme -->
<link href="css/skins/red/red.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" class="skin">

<!-- Favicons -->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/icons/favicon.ico">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="img/icons/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="img/icons/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="img/icons/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">  

<!-- Head Libs -->
<script src="js/modernizr.js"></script>

<!--[if lte IE 9]>
    <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/docs-assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="js/responsive/respond.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!-- styles for IE -->
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie/ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />            
<![endif]-->

<!-- Skins Changer-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

content of footer.php

```
<!-- ======================= JQuery libs =========================== -->
<!-- Always latest version of jQuery-->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <!-- jQuery local-->    
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery.js"><\/script>')</script>    
<!--Nav-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/nav/tinynav.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/nav/superfish.js"></script>  
<script src="js/nav/jquery.sticky.js" type="text/javascript"></script>                                           
<!--Totop-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/totop/jquery.ui.totop.js" ></script>  
<!--Slide-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/slide/camera.js" ></script>      
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/slide/jquery.easing.1.3.min.js'></script>  
<!--Ligbox--> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js"></script> 
<!-- carousel.js-->
<script src="js/carousel/carousel.js"></script>  
<!-- Twitter Feed-->
<script src="js/twitter/jquery.tweet.js"></script> 
<!-- flickr Feed-->
<script src="js/flickr/jflickrfeed.min.js"></script>  
<!--Scroll-->   
<script src="js/scrollbar/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>
<!-- Nicescroll -->
<script src="js/scrollbar/jquery.nicescroll.js"></script>
<!-- Maps -->
<script src="js/maps/gmap3.js"></script>
<!-- Filter -->
<script src="js/filters/jquery.isotope.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--Theme Options-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/theme-options/theme-options.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/theme-options/jquery.cookies.js"></script>                                
<!-- Bootstrap.js-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap/bootstrap.js"></script>
<!--MAIN FUNCTIONS-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
<!-- ======================= End JQuery libs =========================== -->

</body>
```

So when I open index.php - all works fine, and when about.php - css or js brokes.

for example it looks like this:
    index.php - http://joxi.ru/EA4nnnYuKeK0mb.png
    about.php - http://joxi.ru/5mdNNN9FKEK5A1.png

No errors in broswer console

Where can be mistake?

Comment: about and index file both in same folder?

Comment: yes, of course,they in root

Comment: then include both file code here pls. may be you miss some element ?

Comment: must be are mistake with close tags, double check your close tags. Like *where it got closed in index* compare with *where it got closed in about*.

Comment: you can view the view source of about & index in broswer and check the there style css path is matched if yes then click on it check it exist for  both files

Comment: from the browser console, right click on the external css or js file and open them in new tab, what error do you get? pa attention to the url that will be opened. it might help you

Comment: problem not in tags - because about is full copy of index. and there is no one error in browser console

Comment: did you open the external css files from console or page source? did you get 404 error?

Comment: no, they all works fine

Comment: Just take index.php and copy to another folder and rename it to about.php because there must be some error in the code and it it is just a full copy of index you don´t need to worry

Comment: you can copy the same index file in same directory ans name it anyfilename and then check it work fine or not